# Unable to open/edit LESS file in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, less

I have a .LESS file but I'm unable to open/edit it in Visual Studio 2015?

I can open the file fine in sublime text, notepad etc?

Is there something I'm missing in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Hmm, works fine here with VS 2015 Professional... When you say "unable to open", do you mean you get an error message when you do a `File` > `Open` > `File...` to open it in Visual Studio?

Comment: An extension that you have may be crashing when you load a .less file.  Try opening Visual Studio in /SafeMode to disable all extensions:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: @ A.Franklin Well it displays in solution explorer with the LESS icon. When I double click nothing happens. When I right click and select open with, Im displayed with a list of editors to choose from none of which work. I have webessentials 2015 installed, so not sure if thats causing the issue? By the way I have VS 2015 Community version

Comment: I've tried to compile it using web essentials compiler. It compiles the file less file and in solution explorer generates the .css file. Now when I double click the .less file all the happens is that it expands in solution explorer to display the .css file. All I want to do is open the less file so that I can edit it in VS?

Comment: I had to disable web essentials and web workbench for less to start working again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Disabling Workbench worked for me. I didn't have to disable Web Essentials or anything else.